# C++ how to build a getter of a static private member?

Tags: c++, static, private, getter

I am using C++ for a little project of mine.
I want to define a static constant string in a class header file and return this string with a (static) getter.
Here is the header file

```
//*.h
class Authordd : public personDB
{
    public:
        Authordd();
        Authordd(QString dbName, QString dbSurname);
        Authordd(QString dbName, QString dbSurname, unsigned int dbid);
        static std::string getTableName();
    private:
        static const std::string tableName;
};
```

Here is the cpp file:

```
const std::string Authordd::tableName = "Author";

Authordd::Authordd():personDB()
{
    ;
}

Authordd::Authordd(QString dbName, QString dbSurname):personDB(dbName, dbSurname)
{
    ;
}


Authordd::Authordd(QString dbName, QString dbSurname, unsigned int dbid):personDB(dbName, dbSurname)
{
    id = dbid;
}

static std::string getTableName(){
    return (Authordd::tableName);
}
```

Compiling I get the following error:
*/../persondb.cpp:21: error: 'tableName' is a private member of 'personDB'
    return personDB::tableName;*

I have noticed that if I make the ***tablename*** public everything is ok: can I keep this class member private and return it with a static public getter in C++.

Comment: ***static std::string getTableName(){*** You defined a global function not a member of your class.

Comment: The header files declares a **member** function named `getTableName()`; the .cpp file defines a **non-member** function named `getTableName()`.

Comment: the problem is not gone for me

Comment: Edit the question and add line 21 of `persondb.cpp` since that is where the error is. You may need to add a few lines above and below line 21 so we have some context.

Comment: ***the problem is not gone for me*** I think you have more than 1 bug. And the one in the original question is now fixed however we can't solve the one in `persondb.cpp` without seeing the code.

Answer (score 5):

You declared the getter as a method of this class, so you have to define it just like any other method:

```
std::string Authordd::getTableName(){
    return tableName;
}
```

The `static` keyword is used only to declare the class method as static, and it is not involved in the actual method definition.

Comment: removing the static keyword does not solve my problem: it gives me the same error. I tried your implementation but it gives me the same error.

Comment: Correct, and that's why my answer mentions several other things, too.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether this is the ultimate answer, but remove that "static" from the implementation. You're not supposed to write it twice!

You should write these keywords only once inside the class to declare that the function is static.

Comment: That's part of the problem; it's okay as written, because the function being **defined** is not a member function, but it would be wrong for the member function.

Comment: @PeteBecker That's what I meant :)

Comment: removing the static keyword does not solve my problem: it gives me the same error.

Comment: @Rorschach Remove it from the implementation, not from the definition. I.e., remove it from the version outside the class.

Comment: @Rorschach You also forgot to add Authorddd:: before the implementation.

Comment: @The Quantum Physicist Sam Varshavchik in the previous answer made me notice it and I tried its implementation: same as before.

Answer (score 0):

Only the class can access the private member, so the following will allow `main` to  get the static private variable's value:

```
//header.h
#include <string>

class QString {};
class personDB 
{
public:
    personDB() = default;
    personDB(QString dbName, QString dbSurname) {};
};

class Authordd : public personDB
{
public:
    Authordd();
    Authordd(QString dbName, QString dbSurname);
    Authordd(QString dbName, QString dbSurname, unsigned int dbid);
    static std::string getTableName();
private:
    static const std::string tableName;
    int id;
};
```

In the following file we can write a `getTableName()` to call `Authordd::getTableName()`.

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "header.h"

const std::string Authordd::tableName = "Author";

Authordd::Authordd() :personDB()
{
}

Authordd::Authordd(QString dbName, QString dbSurname) : personDB(dbName, dbSurname)
{
}


Authordd::Authordd(QString dbName, QString dbSurname, unsigned int dbid) :personDB(dbName, dbSurname)
{
    id = dbid;
}

std::string Authordd::getTableName()
{
    return Authordd::tableName;
}

static std::string getTableName() {
    return Authordd::getTableName();
}

int main()
{
    auto author_name = getTableName();
    std::cout << author_name << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```